# Коллекция элементов в ConfigSection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, config

При помощи следующего набора классов:

```cs
public class MyConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Items")]
    public ItemCollection Items
    {
        get { return ((ItemCollection)(base["Items"])); }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ItemElement), AddItemName = "Item")]
public class ItemCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    ...
}

public class ItemElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    ...
}
```

Я организую чтение конфигурационной секции следующего вида:

```xml
<MySection>
  <Items>
    <Item ... />
    <Item ... />
    <Item ... />
  </Items>
</MySection>
```

Возможно ли как-то настроить чтение, если я хочу чтобы секция имела вид

```xml
<MySection>
  <Item ... />
  <Item ... />
  <Item ... />
</MySection>
```

т.е. чтобы элементы коллекции не были заключены в `<Items></Items>`, а читались прямо из секции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать параметр `IsDefaultCollection` и пустую строку как ключ:

```
public class MyConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("", Options = ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsDefaultCollection)]
    public ItemCollection Items
    {
        get { return ((ItemCollection)(base[""])); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сработало. С `null` вместо пустой строки - тоже. (Надо же! Впервые вижу место, где `string.Empty` не может быть использовано вместо `""`).

Comment: @i-one: Угу, там нужен строковой литерал.